# Can the functor to empty sets be defined?

Tags: category-theory, functors, presheaves

Can these functors from C to Sets be defined?

1. Functor $F$ from one object $A$ and its identity arrow to a empty set

- $F(A)$ = (empty set)
- $F(id_A)$ = (function from empty set to empty set)

2. Functor G from two objects $A$, $B$ and their identity arrows to a one-element set and a empty set, respectively

- $G(A)$ = $\{*\}$ (one element set)
- $G(B)$ = (empty set)
- $G(id_A)$ = $id_{\{*\}}$
- $G(id_B)$ = (function from empty set to empty set)

I think the latter appears when thinking of Yoneda embedding of the category which has two objects and their identity arrows, is it right?

Comment: Which aspect of defining a functor are you having trouble with? Can you write what you came up with so far?

Comment: I just don't know if it's okay to define functor from object to empty set. Function can't take empty set as a range, but is it allowed for functor?

Comment: It's not clear exactly what you are asking. A functor from $C$ to $\mathbf{Set}$ is defined by a function from $\mathrm{ob}(C)$ to $\mathrm{ob}(\mathbf{Set})$, together with a corresponding assignment on morphisms. It doesn't make sense to write "a functor from one object and its identity arrow to an empty set". Can you write out the functions defining the functor? Then we can verify whether the functions are well defined.

Comment: I added the definition of funtor to the question text above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little ill-formed as it stands, because whether it is possible to define functors $\mathcal C \to \mathbf{Set}$ that have the properties you describe depends on the category $\mathcal C$. However, there are certainly some choices of $\mathcal C$ and functors $F \colon \mathcal C \to \mathbf{Set}$ satisfying these properties.

For the first example, let $\mathcal C$ be a discrete one-object category containing an object $A$. Then the assignment sending $A \mapsto \varnothing$ and $\mathrm{id}_A \mapsto \mathrm{id}_\varnothing$ defines a functor.

For the second example, let $\mathcal C$ be a two-object discrete category having objects $A$ and $B$. Then the assignment sending $A \mapsto \{ * \}$, $\mathrm{id}_A \mapsto \mathrm{id}_{\{ * \}}$, $B \mapsto \varnothing$ and $\mathrm{id}_B \mapsto \mathrm{id}_\varnothing$ defines a functor.

In both cases, we can verify that these define functors by checking that they preserve identities and composites: preservation of identities follows by definition, whereas preservation of composites is trivial, since there are no non-identity morphisms in $\mathcal C$.

However, note that there are some choices of $\mathcal C$ for which we may not define a functor $F \colon \mathcal C \to \mathbf{Set}$ along these lines. For instance, if we take $\mathcal C$ to be a category with two objects $A$ and $B$, and a morphism $f \colon A \to B$ (together with identity morphisms), then there is no functor $F \colon \mathcal C \to \mathbf{Set}$ satisfying the properties of the second example, because that would require us to specify a function from $\{ * \}$ to $\varnothing$, of which there are none.

In summary, we can always define functions (and hence functors) that send some element to the empty set, e.g. there is a (unique) function $\{ * \} \to \{ \varnothing \}$. However, we cannot define non-trivial functions to the empty set, e.g. there is no function $\{ * \} \to \varnothing$. When we define a functor into $\mathbf{Set}$, we are doing something similar to the former, so there is no issue, as long as we can define an action of the functor on morphisms.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question.

Comment: @qS2: you're welcome :) If this answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.